# error uploading images when creating soundcloud app

Tags: soundcloud, uploading

I'm trying to upload images to SoundCloud, to create a new app in the Developers section, but whenever i try to upload the logo and some screenshots puts: "upload failed, please try again". It's been like that for a week and I want to upload our app deej() but I can't submit the app until I upload the images, and there is no way of uploading (I tried with Chrome, IE, Mac, PC but it's always the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Soundcloud Support on this matter, this is not a support forum but related to programming questions.